# Provision to allocate multiple Roles to single User

Tags: apex, visualforce

Just want to know, is there any work around to allocate multiple Roles to a user. The user with multiple roles should able to handle all assigned role's responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

There is no functionality to allow assignments of multiple Roles in the way that a Permission Set allows extension of the Profile's system permissions.

To allow access to records in other parts of a [Role Hierarchy](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_roles.htm&language=en) you can use Sharing Rules or Apex sharing based on either the user's current Role or another part of their profile.

Another option is to use [Public Groups](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=user_groups.htm&language=en_US) for the users to allow access to records without being part of the same Role hierarchy.